# How to redirect the wrong route method to error page in laravel, "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to redirect my post route to error page if the request is not made with post but with get method. But i am getting the error "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."

My route file

```
Route::get('/user/create',[UserController::class, 'create'])->name('user.create');
Route::post('/user',[UserController::class, 'store'])->name('user.store');
```

Into my controller i have used

```
public function store(Request $request){
        

  if($request->isMethod('POST')){
     dd($request->all());
  }else{
     return abort(404);
  }
}
```

So when the route is `Route::post('/user',[UserController::class, 'store'])->name('user.store');` for submitting the data by post method the url is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/user` ok i dont have any problem with that, but when i do hit into my urlbar `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/user` with get method i get the above error but i dont want to show that rather it should get redirected to error page.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/errors#custom-http-error-pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the logic to get a bad method error when someone is requesting a bad method but you can do something like this:

routes file:

```
Route::any('/user',[UserController::class, 'store'])->name('user.store');
```

and in controller:

```
public function store(Request $request){

   if(! $request->isMethod('POST')){
     return abort(404);
   }

   // and the rest of your code for the post request.

}
```

In case you don't want to edit the routes you can replace the exception.

in app/Exceptions/Handler.php add render method:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of exception types with their corresponding custom log levels.
     *
     * @var array<class-string<\Throwable>, \Psr\Log\LogLevel::*>
     */
    protected $levels = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array<int, class-string<\Throwable>>
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'current_password',
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
            //
        });
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Throwable  $e
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     *
     * @throws \Throwable
     */
    public function render($request, Throwable $e)
    {
        if ($e instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
            return abort(404);
        }
        
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
}
```

Comment: actually i cant do that because i have `create` method and i have lots of routes so i need to change a lot, i have tried this it is working too but i cant implement to my one any other method with the controller

Comment: You should customize the error page, run `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors ` and update the blade files like for example : view/errors/404.blade.php

Comment: @TeDeveloper If I understood you correctly you can use match: 
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/user',[UserController::class, 'store'])->name('user.store');
and the same code in the controller.

Comment: No it will not work i have the problem with controller and route, did you got what do i want to say

Comment: Behzad i know this have used a lot but this is not what i do want you can check that in my controller i want the logic to be set here

Comment: I know you don't wanna change the routes but you have to as Laravel first checks the method you provided in the route and throws the 405 exception error before reaching the controller. But you can replace it in the Handler.php I'll edit the answer

Comment: Behzad let me check will let you know